# Problem connecting to MS Office365 e-mail with Evolution

Tags: arch-linux, gnome-keyring, evolution, openrc

I am trying to connect to my workplace's Office365 e-mail with Evolution mail and I am getting the following error when I try to authenticate:

```
Failed to obtain access token from address “https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token”: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.secrets: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.secrets': timed out (service_start_timeout=120000ms)
```

When I try to connect to the mailbox in Evolution, a window pops up with my organization's authentication page; however, when I go through that I get the above error message.

I am using Arch Linux and I have Gnome-Keyring installed; however, I am using OpenRC rather than systemd and I wonder if that might be part of the issue. Does anyone know what might be causing this and how I can connect to an Office365 mailbox with Evolution?

Comment: You have to share, how exactly do you have your Evolution configured.  Of course, remove the passwords or any sensitive information.  Do you have evolution-ews package installed...

Comment: @tukan Sorry for the late reply. I do have `evolution-ews` installed, yes. Regarding the configuration you are requesting - you mean you would like me to post a config file? If so, could you please clarify which one (or what is the most convenient format to provide that information)?

Comment: All connected configuration of your mailbox & office365 server. If i'm correct you need oauth2. How did you get the access token?

Comment: I use davmail and I had to add `davmail.oauth.redirectUri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` to its config, a colleague who uses Evolution said it helped them too but I don't know where exactly should be added there.